# How to Append Large Files Efficiently Using Rsync

Tags: linux, shell, gzip, rsync

In our company, we frequently need to merge multiple large files ranging from 5GB to 200GB in size. These files, compressed in .fastq.gz format, are stored on our storage servers (servers A through H), all mounted to the root folder `/storage/archXX` (mounted with sshfs), where `archXX` represents one of several hard drives on each server. Our production server X serves as the destination for these merged files.

To concatenate these files, we've been using the following command:

```bash
pv /storage/archXX/customerID/fastq/data.fq.gz >> /work/customerID/fastq/data.fq.gz && pv /storage/archYY/customerID/fastq/data.fq.gz >> /work/customerID/fastq/data.fq.gz
```

This method works well since appending .gz files preserves data integrity without loss.

**My Problem:**
However, this method strains our system significantly when transferring these files from storage to production servers, which results in slow data access for my colleagues.

**My Solution:**
To resolve this, I've started using `rsync` to copy the files directly from the archive to our production machine. This solution reduced the load from our systems.

Currently, I'm using the following template to handle multiple files:

```
CustomerID=10
ARCH=arch49
#get the (ssh) path for the wanted archive
ARCH_PATH=$(ssh production "df | grep -w ${ARCH} | sed 's/.*@//'" | awk '{print $1}')
cd /work/${CustomerID}/fastq/
#copy directly to work/CustomerID/fastq/ 
rsync -r -v --progress user@${ARCH_PATH}/${CustomerID}/fastq/* /work/${CustomerID}/fastq/

ARCH=arch51
ARCH_PATH=$(ssh production "df | grep -w ${ARCH} | sed 's/.*@//'" | awk '{print $1}')
cd /work/temp
#copy to work/temp directory
rsync -r -v --progress user@${ARCH_PATH}/${CustomerID}/fastq/* /work/temp/
#append files from /work/temp to /work/CustomerID/fastq/
pv "/work/temp/${CustomerID}_R1.fastq.gz" >> "/work/${CustomerID}/fastq/${CustomerID}_R1.fastq.gz" && pv "/work/temp/${CustomerID}_R2.fastq.gz" >> "/work/${CustomerID}/fastq/${CustomerID}_R2.fastq.gz"
```

This works, but is still inefficient due to unnecessary copies to and from the temporary directory. So I'd like to append to `/work/CustomerID/fastq/data.gz` directly with `rsync`

**The Question:**
While exploring the `rsync` manual, I came across the `--append` flag. According to the manual, this flag only appends to shorter files. I unfortunately can't be sure, that the first file on my server is the shortest, and when appending three or more files, each pair of files copied first, could be larger than the left files.

Do I understand the `--append` flag correctly? Is there another flag for `rsync` that allows me to append files in this way? Does the append function work as I expect it too?

Alternatively, do you have any other ideas on how I can efficiently move these large files through my network?

Comment: soooo why not `ssh user@server cat data.fq.gz >> /work/customerID/fastq/data.fq.gz`? If you don't want rsync, you want to append, then just append.

Comment: In my experience, using ssh and cat with files that reach sizes of tens to few hundreds of GB is not really feasible, because cat uses IO- to read the whole file at once and crashed the system. (but i mostly used it with monitoring output in between) I am trying it right now on a test server. if it's really that simply, I could have saved me a lot of trouble.

Comment: So there are a few points, that I dislike about the ssh & cat solution: 
rsync provides me with the verbose option, that shows me a progress bar. 
when using the ssh & cat solution, I can't get it to work, that I just call the command on * (every file in the source folder) and create/append every correspondent file in my destination folder. Although this could just be me beeing incapable.

Comment: Just `ssh pv` then, it's only the ouptut.

Comment: Yeah, talked with my Boss. Created some artificial problems, when there is a way easier solution. Seems like I needed so. to look from the outside who's not stuck in the problem. 
will post an aswere with the solution or delete the question. 
Thanks for your help.